# Mendeley desktop crash

Tags: 16.04, mendeley

My Mendeley-desktop application suddenly started crashing on Ubuntu 16.04. It says:

**Another application has your Mendeley database open. Closing the other program or logging out of your computer may fix the problem.**

It flashes for a second with this written on the login screen. I have another account 'Administrator' which I think has it opened since when I log in as 'Administrator', the application runs fine. Here is what I have tried:

- reinstall in my account.
- remove it from 'Administrator' account and install in mine.

I cannot get it to work on my account. How does it get it to stop capturing the said database?

**Note**: I can open it in my account using

```
sudo nautilus
```

But I want to be able to run it with my account.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mendeley Desktop only runs with sudo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/844293/mendeley-desktop-only-runs-with-sudo) – found in the side bar while looking for further helpful material for my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you broke the access permissions inside your user home directory by running applications as super-user within the same home directory. You can reset the ownership and thus regain access with:

```sh
sudo chown -R "$USER:" "$HOME"
```

See [Why should users never use normal sudo to start graphical applications?](/q/270006/175814) for an explanation why you shouldn't use `sudo` to start graphical applications and [How do I start Nautilus as root?](/q/156998/175814) for alternatives (applies to other graphical applications too).

Comment: perfect and thanks for the extra info...makes a lot sense

Comment: Dangerous advice. This resets ownership of all the files within home directory, recursively, and is not undo-able. The other answer makes more sense.

Comment: @MostafaFarzán: Technically yes, but I what the intersection of users who 1) can run `sudo`, 2) are unaware what `chown -R` does and 3) have files in their home directories that they should not own, is quite small.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly that was the cause of the problem. 
Mendeley local database located in

> ~/.local/share/data/Mendeley Ltd./Mendeley Desktop/

Hence, one need to change the owner of this folder to the current user.

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.local/share/data/Mendeley Ltd.
```